# Load div content on same page using AJAX in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am newbie on codeigniter but trying to develop simple CMS on it.
my question is i have a side column in my main CMS view which have several links to other views,what i want to do is to load all the links in main CMS view in  center div instead of going to another page every time. I know i can achieve this task through ajax but dont know how to do it on CODEIGNITER.
Here is how i want to acheieve it to my knowledge.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkClick(value){
    jQuery('#mang_server').load(value, 
      function(){alert('Content Successfully Loaded.')} 
                        );
    }

    </script>

<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="header"> <a href="" class="logo"><img src="../img/logo.gif" width="101" height="29" alt="" /></a>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="left-column">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <ul class="nav">
      <?php foreach($ops as $operations)
        {$op_name = $operations['admin_op'];
         $op_link = $operations['link_to'];
        ?>
        <li><a href="" id="" onclick="onLinkClick('<?php echo $op_link ;?>')"><?php echo $op_name ;?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this simple example for [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in codeigniter:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>/controller_namer/method_name', 
     type: 'POST', 
     data: {view_param: "sidebar_html"}, 
     success: function(response){
         $('#div_id').html(response);
     }

});
```

Now go to controllers/controller_name.php and create a method `method_name`;

```
function method_name() {

    // Get Post Data
    $View_Name = $this->input->post("view_param");

    $this->load->view($View_Name);

   // Alternate is create your html here
   // ......
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: And how would I pass parameter through the onclick function call to the ajax.

Comment: i want to pass view name through the parameters.

Comment: jogesh_pi i tried your snippe, but it i think its not working, whenever i click on the link it routes me to login view through the default conrtroller.

Comment: i even tried to debug it with firebug, and also checked if ajax call alert some msg on the response but nothing work.

Comment: @hasn-147 can you provide me the structure of your application? Means controllers folder. Are your using index.php in url?

Comment: No i am not using index.php in the url

Answer (score 0):

@jogesh_pi

View Portion:

```
<script>
    function onLinkClick(value){
    /*Query('#mang_server').load(value, 
                                function(){alert('Content Successfully Loaded.')} 
                        );*/
            $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>/admin/load_view/', 
         type: 'POST',
         data: {view_param: "value"},
         success: function(response){
             //$('#mang_server').html(response);
            alert("response recieved");
         }
    enter code here

    });         


    }
</script>

<li><a href="" id="" onclick="onLinkClick('<?php echo $op_name ;?>')"><?php echo $op_name ;?></a></li>
```

Controller Portion : admin

```
public function load_view($view_name){

$data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name);
$this->load->view($data);




}
```

Model portion : load_view_model

```
public function load_view_model($view_name){

$this->db->where('admin_op',$view_name);
$query = $this->db->get('admin_operations');

if($query->num_rows()>0){

foreach($query->results() as $rows ){

$data['link'] = $rows->link_to;

}

return $data->result_arrays();




}


}
```

Comment: want to know about your model part: what are you doing in this module? cause i see you are storing link_to value in $data['link'] which is not storing, that should be like `$data['link'][]`. and return should be like return $data; where is you defining $data?

Comment: link_to is the database field i am fetching and putting the fetched value in $data['link']. Am i wrong at this point ???